# How do I only set a state variable in a Store if it has not already been set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, isomorphic, hyperstack

I am using [Hyperstack](https://hyperstack.org/) Stores and in the `before_mount` of my component I want to do:

```rb
before_mount do
  BridgeStore.show_card_sample ||= true
end
```

And in the store:

```rb
class BridgeStore < HyperStore
  class << self
    state_accessor :show_card_sample
  end
end
```

But the conditional assignment `||=` is being triggered each time a component of this type is rendered.

I know I can get around this by setting a state variable in the store `state_accessor :is_set` and only set the other variables if that has not been set, but I was wondering if there is a better way round this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the logic around initialization into your store.  Remember that in Ruby your class instance variables can be initialized as the class is defined:

```rb
class BridgeStore < HyperStore
  @show_card_sample = true
  class << self
    state_accessor :show_card_sample
  end
end
```

Comment: You were a hacker before WWII?

Comment: @CarySwoveland close but not quite.  You look pretty experienced yourself